# How to get index of a dynamic JSON object in an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I want to define a function to find index of a JSON object in an array. The JSON object is dynamic.**Here object keys/attributes are not constant in JSON**.

How to find index of matched object (all key& values) in array?

For example:

```
let obj={name:'Bill', phone:'8562456871', email:'bill@email.com'};
let arrayObj=[{street:'wardcircle', city:'Brentwood'},{name:'wan',email:'wan@test.com' },{name:'bill', phone:'8562456871', email:'bill@email.com'}];
let indx=getIndex(obj,arrayObj); // expected result is 2
```

I have defined function like this but it is not working for all dynamic attribute & values:

```
getIndex(obj,arrayObj){
 Object.keys(obj),forEach((key,index)=>{
 return arrayObject.findIndex(x=>x[key]==obj[key]);// Here I am unable to add AND condition for other key& values.
 });
}
```

Comment: Comma instead of a period, `return` inside a `forEach` where it does nothing, no return outside of the `forEach` in a pure function. Please show real code.

Comment: Any reason for down votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `.findIndex` *first*, and inside it, check that `.every` one of the `Object.keys` matches.

Note that your current object has `name: 'Bill'` but the array has `name: 'bill'` - the values should match, case sensitivity matters (unless you want to ignore it, in which case you'll have to call `toLowerCase()` on both values first).

```js
let obj = {
  name: 'bill',
  phone: '8562456871',
  email: 'bill@email.com'
};
let arrayObj = [{
  street: 'wardcircle',
  city: 'Brentwood'
}, {
  name: 'wan',
  email: 'wan@test.com'
}, {
  name: 'bill',
  phone: '8562456871',
  email: 'bill@email.com'
}];


const getIndex = (findObj, array) => (
  array.findIndex(obj => (
    Object.entries(findObj).every(([key, val]) => obj[key] === val)
  ))
);

console.log(getIndex(obj, arrayObj));
```

If you also want to make sure that the found object doesn't have any properties not in the `findObj`, check that the number of keys on both are the  same too:

```js
let obj = {
  name: 'bill',
  phone: '8562456871',
  email: 'bill@email.com'
};
let arrayObj = [{
  street: 'wardcircle',
  city: 'Brentwood'
}, {
  name: 'wan',
  email: 'wan@test.com'
}, {
  name: 'bill',
  phone: '8562456871',
  email: 'bill@email.com'
}];


const getIndex = (findObj, array) => (
  array.findIndex(obj => (
    Object.keys(obj).length === Object.keys(findObj).length &&
    Object.entries(findObj).every(([key, val]) => obj[key] === val)
  ))
);

console.log(getIndex(obj, arrayObj));
```

Comment: I tried your code for these object and array but it giving me incorrect result. Any idea?

`let obj={"street":"10651 Coward Mill Rd","city":"Knoxville","state":"TN","postal":"37931"}`
`let arrayObj=[{"country":"US","default":false,"active":true,"street":"10651 Coward Mill Rd","city":"Knoxville","state":"TN","postal":"37931"}]`

Comment: Plugging in that code gives me a result of 0. That's correct, right? The object is at the 0th index in the array